# Can't seem to enable drag/drop in QListView

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qlistview

I was able to get drag and drop working very easily on a QListWidget where I assign it individual items, but I've since switched to QListView and model/view pattern and I can't seem to get it to work. I'm interested in only allowing the user to reorder the objects in the list, but I don't wish to allow them to actually edit these objects (other than the aforementioned reordering). Here's what I've done:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class AlgorithmListControl(QListView):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(AlgorithmListControl, self).__init__(parent)

        self.parent = parent
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.setDefaultDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)
        self.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
```

For the data model I simply declare a class that inherits from QAbstractListModel, implement the "rowCount" and "data" methods, add a few objects to it and then assign it as the model for the above class via "myAlgorithmList.setModel(myModel)". Everything works up to this point, I can see the objects in the list, their icons appear as they should, the order is correct, etc. However I am unable to reorder them via drag and drop. When I try to drag an item there is no visual indication that the drag mode has initiated and (of course) nothing then happens if I try to drop. It's as if the drag-drop mode hasn't been set. What have I missed? I've hunted around for awhile and nothing is jumping out at me. Might this have something to do with the editability of the model? I've added the following to the model and it had no effect:

```
def flags(self, index):
    return (Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable)
```

Scratching my head on this one.

Update: I've changed the flags statement to the following:

```
def flags(self, index):
    if index.isValid():
        return Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | Qt.ItemIsEnabled
    return Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled | Qt.ItemIsEnabled
```

I am now able to at least drag an item but nothing happens upon release.

Update: After reading the comments I'm adding the code for the model. Apparently the problem resides somewhere in there. I've started to implement the "insertRows()" method of the model, but if I place a breakpoint in that method and attempt a drag-drop operation at runtime the method is apparently never invoked. I'm also unsure about the logic of reordering the list based on the drag-drop in the "insertRows()" method. Any help greatly appreciated:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class AlgorithmSequenceModel(QAbstractListModel):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(AlgorithmSequenceModel, self).__init__(parent)

        self.parent = parent

        # Instantiate an empty list for holding the list of algorithm objects in the proper sequence:
        self.algorithms = list()

        # Do I need this?: self.setSupportedDragActions(Qt.MoveAction)

    def rowCount(self, parent):

        # Return the number of algorithms in the current sequence:
        return len(self.algorithms)

    def flags(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            return Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled
        return Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled | Qt.ItemIsEnabled

    def data(self, index, role):

        # Check the role that's being queried:
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:

            # Retrieve the algorithm and return its name:
            row = index.row()
            return self.algorithms[row].getName()

        if role == Qt.DecorationRole:

            # Retrieve the algorithm and return the icon object reflecting its current state:
            row = index.row()
            return self.algorithms[row].getCurrentStateIcon()

    def setData(self, index, value, role = Qt.EditRole):
        # Data is not editable by user.
        pass

    def insertRows(self, position, rows, parent):

        self.beginInsertRows()

        # Very uncertain how to implement reordering here. Dragged item needs to be removed from its original location and inserted in new location

        self.endInsertRows()


    def addAlgorithm(self, algorithm):

        # Append the algorithm to the end of list:
        self.algorithms.append(algorithm)
```

Comment: I would consider using a `QStandardItemModel` unless you have a pressing need to use a custom model.

Comment: Drop events are forwarded to the model. `QAbstractListModel` has the default implementation of drop events handling which might suffice in your case but the actual model class must still implement at least `insertRows`, `insertColumns` and `setData` methods. Does your model implement these methods?

Comment: @Dmitry: Thank you, but do you mean I need to implement the insertion logic myself in "insertRows"?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. `QAbstractListModel` doesn't reimplement `insertRows` itself and `QAbstractItemModel`'s implementation simply does nothing. Same goes for `removeRows`.

Comment: I've added a (near-empty) "insertRows()" method and set a breakpoint, but apparently this method is never being called at runtime. I'm also unclear as to how to implement the logic in the method. It seems like in "insertRows()"  I need to first remove the item being dragged, and then (re)insert it into the list at the drop location. But how do I get the item being dragged in the first place? And after removing it from the list won't this then alter the drop location?

Comment: @LKeene, that's a little unexpected to me... You could probably debug this by implementing `dropMimeData` method which would do nothing but simply call `QAbstractItemModel`'s `dropMimeData` method with all the same parameters - just to see if it's called at all.
Also, I've just realized you're attempting to implement reordering i.e. the [drop action](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#DropAction-enum) is the move one instead of the default copy. So you won't get away with implementing just `insertRows` and `removeRows`, you'd need your own `dropMimeData` as well.

Comment: @LKeene, some time ago I implemented a kind of such reorderable list model in PyQt5, you can find it [here](https://github.com/d1vanov/PyQt5-reorderable-list-model), there are some explanations about how it works in the readme. Check it out, maybe it'd be useful to you.